# parallelism in Golang loop

Tags: go, parallel-processing, goroutine

I have a project and need to run it on multiple cores of an cpu to get more speed . I have used omplib in fortran but I am not familiar with Golang parallelism . I tried goroutines but that went wrong and made a mess and I got false results. This is my code :

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math"
    "math/rand"
    "os"

    "time"
)

const (
    n_particles int     = 2048
    n_steps     int     = 1000000
    dt          float64 = 1.0
    v0          float64 = 0.50
    radius      float64 = 1.0
    f_intensity float64 = 1.8
    scale       float64 = 32.0
    alpha       float64 = 1.0 / 36.0
)

var (
    x      [n_particles + 1]float64
    y      [n_particles + 1]float64
    angles [n_particles + 1]float64
    vx     [n_particles + 1]float64
    vy     [n_particles + 1]float64
    order  [n_steps + 1]float64
)

func main() {
    /////randomizer
    vstart := time.Now()
    rsource := rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())
    randomizer := rand.New(rsource)

    for i := 0; i <= n_particles; i++ {
        x[i] = (randomizer.Float64()) * scale
        y[i] = (randomizer.Float64()) * scale
        angles[i] = (randomizer.Float64()) * math.Pi * 2
        sin, cos := math.Sincos(angles[i])
        vx[i] = v0 * cos
        vy[i] = v0 * sin
    }
    //////main loop
    for i := 0; i <= n_steps; i++ {
        start := time.Now()

        for j := 0; j <= n_particles; j++ {
            x[j] = x[j] + (vx[j] * dt)
            //x[j] = math.Mod(x[j], scale)
            if x[j] < 0.0 {
                x[j] = x[j] + scale
            }
            if x[j] >= scale {
                x[j] = x[j] - scale
            }
            y[j] = y[j] + (vy[j] * dt)
            //y[j] = math.Mod(x[j], scale)
            if y[j] < 0.0 {
                y[j] = y[j] + scale
            }
            if y[j] >= scale {
                y[j] = y[j] - scale
            }

        }
        type intpos struct {
            x, y int64
        }
        adjacencyIndex := make(map[intpos][]int)
        ////getting each boxes particles
        for j := 0; j <= n_particles; j++ {
            // . . .
            ix, iy := int64(math.Floor(x[j])), int64(math.Floor(y[j]))                 // getting particle box
            adjacencyIndex[intpos{ix, iy}] = append(adjacencyIndex[intpos{ix, iy}], j) // adding particles to boxes
        }
        /////////
        m_angles := angles
```

Now I want following loop run in parallel :

```
////particle loop - I WANT FOLLOWING LOOP PARALLEL

    for j := 0; j <= n_particles; j++ {

        sumanglesx := 0.0
        sumanglesy := 0.0
        ix, iy := int64(math.Floor(x[j])), int64(math.Floor(y[j]))
        // fxi = math.Floor(x[j])
        // fyi = math.Floor(y[j])

        for dx := -1; dx <= 1; dx++ {
            for dy := -1; dy <= 1; dy++ {
                adjacentParticles := adjacencyIndex[intpos{ix + int64(dx), iy + int64(dy)}]

                for _, k := range adjacentParticles {

                    dist := ((x[k] - x[j]) * (x[k] - x[j])) + ((y[k] - y[j]) * (y[k] - y[j]))

                    if dist < radius {

                        sy, sx := math.Sincos(angles[k])

                        if k <= j {
                            sumanglesx = sumanglesx + sx
                            sumanglesy = sumanglesy + sy
                        } else {
                            sx = alpha * sx
                            sy = alpha * sy
                            sumanglesx = sumanglesx + sx
                            sumanglesy = sumanglesy + sy
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        bsource := rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())
        bandomizer := rand.New(bsource)
        sumanglesy = sumanglesy
        sumanglesx = sumanglesx
        r_angles := math.Atan2(sumanglesy, sumanglesx)
    }
}
}
```

I specified one loop which should run parallelly .

Comment: Sorry, what's the question exactly?

Comment: I would suggest you break-up your main function into functions (including passing and returning values, and relying relying on global variables). It would then be easier to see which part of your code can be called in parallel via Goroutines.

Comment: @elliot-savoni on StackOverflow you should specify the error message of what went wrong. Please be more explicit on "hat went wrong and made a mess and I got false results"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two approaches to try out: https://play.golang.org/p/O1uB2zzJEC5

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
  waitGroupApproach()
  channelApproach()
}

func waitGroupApproach() {
    fmt.Println("waitGroupApproach")
    var waitgroup sync.WaitGroup
    
    result_table := make([]int, 6, 6)
    
    for j := 0; j <= 5; j++ {
        waitgroup.Add(1)
        
        go func(index int) {
            fmt.Println(index) // try putting here `j` instea of `index`
            result_table[index] = index*2
        
            waitgroup.Done()
        }(j) // you have to put any for-loop variables into closure
        // because otherwsie all routines inside will likely get the last j == n_particles + 1
        // as they will likely run after the loop has finished
    }
    
    fmt.Println("waiting")
    waitgroup.Wait()
    // process results further
    fmt.Println("finished")
    fmt.Println(result_table)
}

func channelApproach() {
    fmt.Println("\nchannelApproach")
    
    type intpos struct {
            x, y, index int
        }

    results := make(chan intpos)

    // initialize routines
    for j := 0; j <= 5; j++ {
        go func(index int) {
            // do processing
            results <- intpos{index*2, index*3, index}          
        }(j)
    }
    fmt.Println("Waiting..")
    
    // collect results, iterate the same number of times
    result_table := make([]int, 6)
    for j := 0; j <= 5; j++ {
        r := <- results
        // watch out order, migth not be the same as in invocation, 
        // so that's why I store j in results as well
        fmt.Println(r.index, r.x, r.y)
        result_table[r.index] = r.x
    }
    fmt.Println("Finished..")
    fmt.Println(result_table)
}
```

I prefer the channel approach because it's more go idiomatic to me and it allows to easier handle panic, error conditions, etc.